# Is there a "Votebox" software out there for any company to use?

Tags: web-apps, issue-tracker, hosted

Awhile back Dropbox had a Votebox, a way for users to vote on which issues they considered to be the most important to prioritize:

[image: Screenshot of 'Votebox', a web page listing feature requests for Dropbox]

I'm wondering - is there some platform as a service out there that offers a votebox-like functionality for any company to use? It's a neat solution that I would like to experiment with, but I can't seem to find any off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: Haven't checked out how one uses it, but have you seen UserVoice.Org?

Comment: @Izzy uservoice.COM looks like it might offer something similar. Uservoice.ORG is some sort of offender help website or something ;).

Comment: Ooops... should have verified the domain before posting, sorry. Just remembered the 2nd-level-part (I don't use it often).